# How regular users should deal with a spam?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes there is a spam on Answers, e.g. like today. So, how regular users should deal with it? I mean those ones who have insufficient karma to delete the entire question/answer/comment.

For example, my karma is enough to *Close* a question, but not to delete it. However, for the answers and comments there is only *Delete* option which I cannot use.

I tried to downvote some of the spam answers today, but got negative points for this. Probably because it was several answers from the same user.

So should it be left for moderators (are there any?) or we have to take some action too?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59325/how-regular-users-should-deal-with-a-spam?/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-26**:
That tommox is annoying. We cannot do anything but wait for administrator to block his account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you click the "flag offensive" button (above comments, below the post), it will put the message into a queue for moderators (and remove it from visibility).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-26**:
Is it easy to find all the comments made from spammers account? Because this time spambot(?) not just created the questions, but also answers.  And the only option for answers and comments is *Delete*, it is not possible to flag it. I was thinking that downvoting can help moderators to identify spam

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
So I see a "flag offensive" next to this answer (although not on comments). Do you not have that option? Perhaps there is some other setting that is wrong which is requiring a high karma level for flagging answers.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-26**:
Yeah, I don't have this option, only 'delete' and 'link'.

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-26**:
Haha! I only have 'link'. Not even have 'delete'.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-26**:
That is actually weird, I have 'delete', but I can't use it -- it says that over 1000 karma is required.

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-26**:
very funny :-D

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-03-27**:
I have edit, delete and link on this answer and edit, retag, close, delete on the question. No flag offensive. (But since i got >1000 karma, i probably dont need it anymore) Is there a possibility to see the moderators? And all my flagged posts remained visible in the past. (at least to me...)

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-03-27**:
Nice to see I'm not [the only one](http://answers.ros.org/question/52446/meta-karma-vs-buttons-curiosities-no-edit-but-a-delete-button-on-anwersros/). [Askbot upstream post done](http://askbot.org/en/question/10327/karma-vs-buttons-curiosities-eg-not-working-delete-button/).

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2013-03-27**:
@Boris the "delete" button issue is a bug indeed, I will try to fix it asap on this site.

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2013-03-27**:
@felix k thank you for bringing these up, I will fix these within 3 days (possibly need to do some work to update the theme to the current version of Askbot as well).